# modules.usbmap and modules.pcimap missing on Ubuntu-based distro

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have been learning Kernel programming and taking the [Eudyptula challenge](http://eudyptula-challenge.org/), and task 5 requires me to modify a hello world module from an earlier task to be automatically loaded when a USB keyboard is plugged, and unloaded when the keyboard is unplugged.

Now, for the sake of it, I will not be posting my code here, because that would be a huge spoiler for this task and would ruin the fun of it for others. Basically, what it does is:

1. Creates a `struct usb_device_id` array with one entry that binds my module to any usb keyboard
2. Creates a `struct usb_driver` and initializes the proper fields; in particular, it references the usb device id table array that I created previously
3. Uses the macro `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE` to register the driver.

The register / unregister routines are working. I get the expected debugging messages when I manually load and unload the module.

I copied the module to `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` and ran `depmod -a`. The module is added to `modules.alias` and `modules.dep`, but nothing happens when I plug / unplug the keyboard.

Further research showed that I should have a `modules.usbmap` file generated by `depmod` where the kernel keeps a mapping between devices and drivers to load. I don't have this file anywhere in my folders tree. I also don't have a `modules.pcimap`. I have checked the kernel configuration to make sure that loadable module support is enabled, as well as hotplugging support - they are.

This is Kubuntu 14.04 with self-compiled 3.16.0-rc5 kernel. What am I missing? I have gone through the kernel configuration and checked the most obvious options. I'm kind of stuck here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You might be missing two things:

1.) An USB keyboard is typically not just a generic USB device, but a HID class device. Linux treats USB HID devices as a separate subclass. Have you taken this into account?

2.) modules.usbmap and modules.pcimap exist with some older versions of module/pci/usb utilities only. With modern versions, the information equivalent to what used to be in those files is included in modules.alias instead. Your research materials may have been obsolete.

Comment: I eventually made it, though I never got the module to load every time I plugged / unplugged the keyboard. Apparently, I was having a similar problem to http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/driver-development-usbhid-is-blocking-custom-device-driver-850287 - if I unload `usbhid`, then my module works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions..

1. Try registering by using vendor_id, product_id and check whether you are registering the for the correct hardware device.

You can try writing a rule in

> /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules

make sure it is identifying your hardware correctly. Following commands may help you:

```
udevadm monitor or udevadm monitor --env
udevadm info -a -p [/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1 -> this has to be get from above command]
```

2. Make sure you `rmmod` your module, clean all logs [`sudo dmesg -c`] and plug in the hardware.